# Deleting data under a key in Firebase

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I delete data stored under a specific key in Firebase using Javascript? The key is generated by Firebase itself and I'm not sure how to reference to the specific key that I would like to delete.

The database is as below:

[image]

I would like to delete a specific child's data, in this case I would like to delete the child stored in the key: -LO1M0u_xW4MrolCTwrg

Here is my code:

```
 function deleteComplaintPothole(){
    var deleteComplaint= firebase.database().ref("complaintsPothole/complaintId");
    deleteComplaint.remove();
    document.getElementById("complaints").innerHTML='';
    readComplaints();
 }
```

[Here is a screenshot of the website showing the complaints with its delete button:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdQzs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the official **Firebase Database Web** guide:

[image]

Then, you could use **orderByChild** and **equalTo** like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('complaintsPothole').orderByChild('complaintId').equalTo('-LO1M0u_xW4MrolCTwrg').remove();
```

You can find more informations here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, how do you have a reference to the other different child keys? I would like to show the complaints from the database with their own delete button and I can't figure out how the delete button can be referred to the specific child keys. I've also edited the original post to have a screenshot of the complaints with its delete button.

Comment: @HarithAliman you can store complaintId in HTML attribute like data-complaint="firebase_ref_id". After you retrieve it with jQuery. You cand find more informations about data-attribute here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to understand how to implement it that way. Can you help me with the sample code?

Comment: Here you can see an example implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/qg7nL6fm/

Comment: I get "TypeError: firebase.database(...).ref(...).orderByChild(...).equalTo(...).remove is not a function[Learn More]" when I implement the code. Is there anywhere else I can contact you on?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Marco Dal Zovo

Finally found the solution. Here is my code:
**

```
function deleteComplaintPothole(){
    $(document).on('click', '.card-body', function(complaintsId){
    var complaintsId = $(this).attr('data-complaint-id');       
    console.log(complaintsId);
    var query = firebase.database().ref("complaintsPothole").orderByChild("complaintId").equalTo(complaintsId);
    query.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
     snapshot.ref.remove();
     window.location.reload();
});
});
 }
```

**